# JQ usage to filter content

Tags: linux, jq

I want to filter and get the results of each index that

it's name starts with `"abc"` and the state is `"DISABLED"`.

My file looks like this:

```json
➜  ~ cat test.json | head
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Name": "abcd",
      "Arn": "arn:aws:events:eu-west-2:XXXXXX:rule/abcd",
      "State": "ENABLED",
      "ScheduleExpression": "rate(6 hours)",
      "EventBusName": "default"
    },
    {
      "Name": "abcxxx",
      "Arn": "arn:aws:events:eu-west-2:XXXXXX:rule/abcxxx",
      "State": "DISABLED",
      "ScheduleExpression": "rate(12 hours)",
      "EventBusName": "default"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use this command:

```bash
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | .[] |  select(.Name | startswith("abc"))'
```

And it's giving me whatever starts with `"abc"` which is good but I want it to be also
`.State == "DISABLED"` and I want the output to be regular and not JSON.
(I need to get the names of whatever starts with `abc` and it's state is `DISABLED` into a file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a second condition with the [and](https://devdocs.io/jq/index#and/or/not) operator will allow you to filter with your 2 conditions:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | .[] |  select((.Name | startswith("abc")) and .State == "DISABLED")
```

Then to extract `Name` field

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | .[] |  select((.Name | startswith("abc")) and .State == "DISABLED") | .Name'
```

Comment: UUOC (useless use of cat): jq can open files or IO redirection can be used: `<test.json jq -r '.[] …'`

Answer (score 1):

You can either combine two selects or combine your conditions with `and`:

```
.Rules[] | select(.State == "DISABLED" and (.Name | startswith("abc"))) | .Name
```

```
.Rules[] | select(.State == "DISABLED") | .Name | select(startswith("abc"))
```